# how to apache-fix kafka error when mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: apache-kafka

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
```

Comment: please provide the configuration files in order for people to be able to troubleshoot your problem

Comment: Can you share the code and the configuration properties?